# CakePHP Recommended syntax for templates (views)

Tags: php, cakephp

Ever since i've used CakePHP, I asked myself about the deeper sense of the recommended syntax of CTP-files, which is basically a HTML-file with all PHP code bracketed with  tags. I find this very hard to read and I should think that the context switches between HTML and PHP would add some performance penalty.
Wouldn't it be faster and clearer to collect all output in a string and echo it at the end?
But there is some deeper sense for sure, just that i don't see it.. 
To make myself clearer, here's an example:

CakePHP:

```
<?php if (!empty($file['User']['email'])): ?>
<div class="mailto"><?php echo $this->Html->link($file['User']); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!empty($file['Document']['comments'])): ?>
<div class="file-comment file-extra column grid_6">
<div class="content"><?php echo $file['Document']['comments']?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My approach:

```
<?php
$out = '';
if (!empty($file['User']['email'])) {
 $out .= '<div class="mailto">'.$this->Html->link($file['User']).'</div>';
}
if (!empty($file['Document']['comments'])) {
 $out .= '<div class="file-comment file-extra column grid_6">'
  .'<div class="content">'.$file['Document']['comments'].'</div>'
  .'</div>';
}
echo $out;
?>
```

So my question is: What are the drawbacks to my approach compared to CakePHP's ?

Comment: `the context switches between HTML and PHP would add some performance penalty` - this doesn't exist. As shown by the formatting of the question one obvious drawback is you lose code formatting doing that. The question is however [off topic, as it is opinion based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Both code examples are horrible to read - IMO. And I personally think your approach is even more bad to read. It's just a matter of formatting and indentation not the language or its syntax. Suggested read: https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: Admitted, I didn't bother to add linefeeds and indentation. How would you write it differently except for adding linefeeds/indentation? Perhaps there's an altogether different way to do it? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: This is all opinion based. But I prefer the CakePHP approach with indentation of both if statements and html.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: writing your entire template as PHP, then echoing it is not a great idea. As a general rule of thumb, I avoid echoing HTML from PHP ever, if I can. there are many reasons, but the main one will be the lack of syntax highlighting in your IDE.

Anyway, code formatting is entirely down to personal preference, but if you're writing your templates like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($file['User']['email'])): ?>
<div class="mailto"><?php echo $this->Html->link($file['User']); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!empty($file['Document']['comments'])): ?>
<div class="file-comment file-extra column grid_6">
<div class="content"><?php echo $file['Document']['comments']?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...it's no wonder you can't read them.

---

There are a few things you could try, to make your code clearer and easier to read. Again, these are down to your own personal preferences, and you could get into the habit of using some or all of them.

- Format your HTML properly, with indentations for child elements.
- Add white space between lines of code that are too busy, particularly between lines of PHP and lines of HTML.
- Use short echo tags syntax (`<?=` instead of `<?php echo`).
- Assign the more complex PHP values to variables so that your HTML is easier to read.
- Remember to comment your code (HTML or PHP), particularly adding HTML comments so that you can easily see separate components of your template at a glance.

**Example**

```
<?php
    $user = $file['User'];
    $comments = $file['Document']['comments'];
?>

<!-- User --> 

<?php if (!empty($user['email'])) : ?>

<div class="mailto"><?= $this->Html->link($user); ?></div>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- File Comments -->

<?php if (!empty($comments)) : ?>

<div class="file-comment file-extra column grid_6">
    <div class="content"><?= $comments; ?></div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```